# Using 2 different outputs of 'return' of a function in separate elements of a plot

Tags: function, matplotlib, return-value

> I am drawing a plot of voltage per time. For the voltage values, I want the values to be evaluated by a 'scaling' function which converts the values from volts to kilovolts if the biggest element is higher than 1000 volts (**11000 volts** to **11 KILOvolts**).
>
> This function is supposed to return 2 separate outputs; one for (new) **values** of voltage and one for the **unit**. The **values** are fed into the **y axis** values of the plot and the **unit** is given to the **labeling** line of that axis. For example:

```
import numpy as np
time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
system_voltage1 = np.array([110, 120, 130, 150])
system_voltage2 = np.array([11000, 12000, 13000, 15000])
```

```
scaling_function(input)
    if np.amax(input) < 1000:
        output = input/1
        Voltage_label = 'Voltage in Volts'
    if np.amax(input) > 1000:
        output = input/1000
        Voltage_label = 'Voltage in KILOVolts'
    return(output, Voltage_label)
```

```
fig14 = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax1 = fig14.add_subplot(111)

l1, = ax1.plot(time, scaling_function(system_voltage), color='r')
ax1.set_xlabel("time in second", color='k')
ax1.set_ylabel(Voltage_label, color='k')
```

> Now, I am having trouble, calling this function properly. I need the function to only receive the `output` for `scaling_function(system_voltage)`, and receive `Voltage_label` in `ax1.set_ylabel(Voltage_label, color='k')`. Now:

**A)** **My problem**: I don't know how to write the code so only the first output is received and used for `scaling_function(system_voltage)` , and the second element for the labeling line.

**B)** **Something I tried but didn't work:**`Voltage_label` does not recognize the value of voltage_label from scaling_function, as it is located in an outer loop than the function. I mean,  I cannot access voltage_label as its value is not **globally** assigned.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

```
y,l = scaling_function(system_voltage)
l1, = ax1.plot(time, y, color='r')
ax1.set_xlabel("time in second", color='k')
ax1.set_ylabel(l, color='k')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without saving them in different variables?

Comment: No. But I would suggest you think about this: you don't need to scale your data. You only need to scale the y-axis values.